# Silverlight 3 different behavior between browsers

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, prism

I have a silverlight project that runs normally, its just a listbox that retrieivies some value. This project run correctly in Internet explorer but do not runs correctly in Safari 4 or Firefox 3.5....
Does silverlight have some difference in terms of behavior that can vary from browser to browser?

Here's the error that happens in the non IE Browsers

> Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Charset" Error:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while saving
>   changes. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Services.Http.WebException: Internal error at
>   'HttpWebResponse.NormalizeResponseStatus'.
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Http.HttpWebResponse.NormalizeResponseStatus(Int32&
>   statusCode)
>
> at System.Data.Services.Http.HttpWebResponse..ctor(HttpWebRequest
>   request, Int32 statusCode, String responseHeaders)
>
> at System.Data.Services.Http.HttpWebRequest.CreateResponse()
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Http.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryAsyncResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObjectInfo.Invoke(ManagedObject
>   obj, InvokeType invokeType, String memberName, ScriptParam[] args)
>
> at System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObject.Invoke(InvokeType
>   invokeType, Int32 memberID, ScriptParam[] args)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Hosting.ScriptingInterface.InvokeScriptableMember(ManagedObject
>   obj, InvokeType invokeType, Int32 memberID, ScriptParam[] args,
>   ScriptParam& pResult)
>
> at System.Windows.Hosting.ManagedHost.InvokeScriptableMember(IntPtr
>   pHandle, Int32 nMemberID, Int32 nInvokeType, Int32 nArgCount,
>   ScriptParam[] pArgs, ScriptParam& pResult, ExceptionInfo& pExcepInfo)

Comment: When you say "does[sic] not run correctly in ..." what do you mean by run correctly? Does anything load?

Comment: Yes, the listbox loads, when i click in the simple button to recover data nothing happens in other browsers..
I'm using prism with ado.net dataservices.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight uses the HTTP stack provided by the host browser to access data from the server. Hence there can be variations in the way HTTP behaves from one browser to another.  This looks like it may be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Anthony wrote, you can switch from Browser HTTP stack, which is used by default to Silverlight HTTP stack (introduced in Silverlight 3, AFAIR).

As long as I faced similar problem and found a solution, I wrote a [post](http://bazzilic.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/silverlight-httpwebresponse-status-code-other-than-200-ok-or-404-not-found/) elaborating on this with some code samples.